# Exceeding application_name character length

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL in my project. I'm setting the `application_name` in my app. According to docs, the `application_name` character length can only be less than `NAMEDATALEN`, which is 64 characters by default.

However, only for this particular purpose (`application_name` in `pg_stat_activity`) I need to exceed this cap. Is there any way how to achieve this other than changing the `NAMEDATALEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you'd have to recompile PostgreSQL with non-default settings.

Maybe you can use a table to communicate your data.

Comment: Unfortunately that seemed like the only option to me as well; just wanted to make sure. Then I will have to create a separate table or just try to shorten the content. Thanks for your answer.